# android TextView setText not working

Tags: android, textview

I know there are a lot of similar threads but I've gone through them and still can't figure out the problem.  My program reaches the Handler but it always returns the catch exception "Message isn't handled."

I declared the TextView `private TextView chatbox;`

Under onCreate I have:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setUpViews();
        setUpListener();
    }
```

where setUpViews() snippet looks like:

```
 private void setUpViews() {
    chatbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatbox);
    }
```

Handler:

```
public Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            try{
                chatbox.setText("Got it!");
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("MYLOG", "Message was not handled.");
            }

        }
    };
```

Snippet in main.xml file:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatbox"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 55):

For future reference, I had multiple fragments, one for each tab in my ViewPager. One TextView had the same `id` in two fragments and that created a conflict. I didn't realize I had the same `id` so everything seemed fine, no error message, but the text simply didn't change. Therefore I'd recommend using unique names for the `id`.

Comment: I've encountered with same issue. And wondering why it should be unique, if different pages have same layout. In my case setting different id didn't work, but textView.requestLayout() did the thing,
also worked for me:
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I had a similar problem, with a TextView in the Activity with the same id of a TextView in a RecyclerView(same Activity). When findViewById() was called for the first TextView, it was mixing the reference with a TextView in the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you handler is running in UI Thread. Also try doing this: Assign your string to a variable and use that variable as it requires charsequence.

```
String temp = "Got it!";
chatbox.setText(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us much to go on.

You should look at the exception stack trace, instead of printing a message to the console: `e.printStackTrace();`

But from here, if I had to guess, it looks like you're either setting the TextView's text off the main thread, or - and which appears unlikely based on what you've posted - your TextView has not been set and you have a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found there are a `TextWatcher` and a `Filter` linked to my `Textview`, which both contain a logic that prevents the updating of my `Textview` value.
So additionally to other solutions, you can check if your `Textview` is linked to any `TextWatcher` or `Filter` and then trace it.

Answer (score 1):

when the textColor is the same as View's background color ,the text also sees invisible ,so you can define a textColor to solve it

Answer (score 0):

just like this is ok!

```
private void setUpViews() {
    chatbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatbox);
    chatbox.setText("Got it!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you send a message?
for example:

```
            Message message=new Message();
        message.what=1;
        mHandler.sendMessage(message);
```